# If you blow up MegaTon where do you go to continue with the main quest?

Tags: fallout-3

In fallout 3 my first time playing it I was suppose to find information about my father at MegaTon. Well, I decided to blow up MegaTon instead. (via that one guy from Tempenny Tower). Where do I go after I blow up MegaTon to continue with the main quest of the game(finding my father)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can still follow the entire main quest without skipping anything but the Megaton parts.

You'll have to go to Galaxy News Radio and talk to Three Dog. More information about that can be found on the [Fallout Wikia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Following_in_His_Footsteps#Galaxy_News_Radio).

Answer (score 6):

You have to visit Rivet City. Talk to Miss Li (she's a doctor) in the lab.
Don't forget to pick up the "Vault doll" on her table ;)

Comment: That would skip a part of the main quest that doesn't have to be skipped.

Comment: Actually I already knew this answer but thought it was a good question... I followed this route, but next time I set out to beat it I think I'll follow @Arda's advice

Comment: @ArdaXi - whilst yes, skipping GNR would skip that part of the main story - the quest (to get the Satelite Dish for GNR) is still achievable, and actually involves a different reward: A key and location to a weapons cache (not lockpick-able) as opposed to info on your Dad.